If ‘provincial’ is the adjective for provinces what is the adjective form of ‘dominions’?
I have two category of territories: Provinces and Dominions. Adjective for everything from provinces is provincial. Like Provincial Government, Provincial Roads, Provincial Courts etc.
What is a similar adjective for Dominions? Government of Dominion, Roads of Dominions etc. is starting to sound weird because I have to use them often.

Is it a historical context? You could use it as an attributive noun Dominion roads/courts etc.

You could try to find out what the Dominions of the British Empire used, but I suspect it was simply attributive as @fev suggests.

@fev Is that like 'state' in 'state courts' instead of  an adjective like 'national' or 'federal'? Will 'Dominion Courts' also flow just as smoothly for the reader?

@AndrewLeach I tried it. Looked through this. 121 times word dominion was used and not a single one them was used as an attributive noun. "Territories of the Dominions", "Legislation of the Dominions" they always used the long version. But, then again, this is official document, so maybe that is on purpose.

It is unclear what you mean when you say 'I have two categor[ies] of territories'. In what sense do you have them, so that you would need to use the term you are seeking? What is the context? The answer given below by LPH may be technically correct, but won't be readily understood by the majority of the present-day English speakers, who are likely to have encountered the term dominion only in the contexts that have to do with the history of the British Commonwealth.

@jsw29 I have the two categories of territories in a fictional empire. Dominions in this fiction kingdom are no different from the historical British Dominions i.e. largely autonomous . Provinces are territories that are under complete administrative control of the empire.

The adjective would be "dominial".

(SOED) dominial  [f. DOMINION + -AL1] Of or pertaining to ownership.

(An Economic Survey of Ancient Rome: Haywood, R. M. Roman ...Tenney Frank · 1975) ...  The regions assigned to dominial and other procurators from Vespasian on had foreshadowed a system of organization involving smaller territorial units.
Philadephia of Lydia became the center of a dominial region […].

This is very rare (I can't find it in any of the usual reputable freely available online dictionaries) and I'd expect to see an attributive usage or workaround instead.

@EdwinAshworth OED citation: “1876 Such a right was dominial rather than marital, and belonged to a man not so much as husband but as slave-owner. (Westminster Review No. 98. 333)” They have put it in Frequency Band 1, which is least common, but not marked it as rare. 18% of non-obsolete words are in band 1, 45% in band 2. The thing is that this is about ownership.

I came across this in when I was searching the web for an appropriate adjective but didn't use it as I was concerned average reader might not be familiar with the term. As @EdwinAshworth pointed out even most dictionaries seem to miss this.

@tchrist 'dominial rather than marital' is almost certainly using the sense 'relating to dominion' rather than 'relating to a dominion'. So even OED seems not to offer the 'relating to a dominion as opposed to state / province' sense (or you'd have shown this). I doubt OED lists frequencies by polyseme.

I'd guess that the Saxon genitive was used if required:

'the dominion's roads' etc. But this count usage of 'dominion' is rare nowadays.

In related usages, the synonym 'domain' is often used attributively ('domain name' etc), and this is another possibility.

domain [noun]:
c. 1600, "territory over which dominion is exerted," from French
domaine "domain, estate," from Medieval Latin domanium "domain,
estate," from Latin dominium "property, dominion," from dominus "lord,
master, owner," from domus "house" (from PIE root *dem- "house,
household"). A later borrowing from French of the word which became
demesne.
... Internet domain name is attested by 1985. [Though this is of course a broadened sense,] 'range or limits of any department of knowledge or sphere of action'.

[Online Etymological Dictionary]
